# Online game task time, what to use? Cron Jobs?

Tags: php, database, cron, clock, countdown

Well, I'm trying to develop something like what happens with online games. For example, lets say you want to upgrade something on the game(web-browser game).

You click, then comes a countdown clock and only when this "clock" finishes your "something" is upgraded.Another thing is that you don't need to be online when the countdown becomes zero to make your "something" upgrade.

I wonder how is this done using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going at the problem in a very "imperative" way:

1. Start something
2. Wait a little
3. Mark it as finished

You can achieve the same result by looking at it differently:

- At time X, the upgrade is started
- At time X+t, the upgrade is complete

so when starting the upgrade, you store the current time + either the duration or the time it finishes. To the user you display:

- Before everything: A button to start the upgrade
- After the start: A countdown for the remaining time until X+t is reached
- After X+t: The "upgrade completed" message

If you need to also modify other variables depending on the status of the upgrade (eg. health points) don't think of it as modifying the value of HP in the database after the upgrade has completed. Calculate the HP based on the history of completed upgrades.

Comment: So you're saying I should save on my database the increment along with time and then check the "history" of the actions...

Comment: How about performance? Isn't this a bad way?

Comment: Caching in such a situation is very simple, since you can store the computed values + the current time on access, so you only have to consider everything since the date of the cache. Depending on the database system you can also use (materialized) views for your computed values and let the DB do the optimizations.